# Unable to delete Realm database in Realm dotnet 2.1.0

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, realm, dispose

Using Realm dotnet 2.1.0 in a Xamarin Forms project, I'm unable to delete the database due to the "Unable to delete Realm because it is still open" message.

This has only been an issue since upgrading to 2.1.0, previously we were using Realm 0.80.

Here's our full database removal method:

```
public void RemoveDatabase()
{
  // Remove all content.
  try
  {
    ClearCachedDataItems();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //Logging removed
  }

  try
  {
    // Close all connections
    using (var realm = GetRealmInstance())
    {
      if (realm != null)
      {
        realm.Dispose();
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //Logging removed
  }
  try
  {
    // Drop the nuke.
    var config = GetRealmConfiguration();
    var delete = false;

    using (var realm = Realms.Realm.GetInstance(config))
    {
      if (config != null)
      {
        delete = true;
      }
      realm.Dispose();

    }

    if (delete)
    {
      Realms.Realm.DeleteRealm(config); // fails here
    }

  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //Logging removed
  }
}

public Realms.Realm GetRealmInstance()
{
  var config = GetRealmConfiguration();

  if (config == null)
  {
    return null;
  }

  return Realms.Realm.GetInstance(config);
}
```

I added the using statements based on this git post: https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/1545

Is there a way to get all running instances of local Realms?

I'm also concerned that I'm creating a new instance of Realm in the final steps when I just want to check a local instance.

Comment: I'm actually getting this same error with my app. I'm targeting Net Standard 2.0 and have Relam.Database 3.2. I tried using the dispose pattern but it still throws and error saying it's not closed even after the dispose.